# Bash script what is := for?

Tags: bash, scripting, colon-equals

Does anyone know what is := for?

I tried googling but it seems google filters all symbol?

I know the below is something like checking if the variable HOME is a directory and then something is not equal to empty string.

```
  if [ "${HOME:=}" != "" ] && [ -d ${HOME} ]
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> `${parameter:=word}`

> *If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to
> parameter. The value of parameter is
> then substituted. Positional
> parameters and special parameters may
> not be assigned to in this way.*

Basically it will assign the value of `word` to `parameter` if and only if `parameter` is unset or null.

Comment: I've seen := a lot of places. Ussually I read it is "defined by". In C++, C#, Java (+ a hundred other places) := equals =. And when this is true, ussually = equals ==. Wow - that was a subtle point by me. Sorry for being so bad at explaining myself :)

Comment: @Meeh: As far as I know, this is the only situation where bash uses ":=". For assignment, "=" is used and for equality comparison, either "=" or "==" can be used. Bash also accepts assignment operators like "+=". I'm not sure which operator you're saying C++, etc., use, but it's "=". Languages like Pascal and Ada use ":=" and so might be considered to be rarer.

Answer (score 2):

From the Bash man page:

> Assign  Default  Values.   If 
>   parameter  is  unset or null, the
>   expansion of word is assigned to
>   parameter.  The value of parameter 
>   is  then  substituted.   Positional
>   parameters and special parameters may
>   not be assigned to in this way.

Man pages are a wonderful thing. `man bash` will tell you almost everything you want to know about Bash.